# Activating keyboard macros from mouse? (ROCCAT)

Tags: keyboard, mouse

I'm using a RYOS MK PRO Keyboard together with a TYON mouuse, I would like to record a macro on the keyboard and play it with a mouse button, is it possible?, couldn't find it easily.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if either of those peripherals have software which include macro editing.

Your best bet would probably be to download autohotkey and create a macro on there, and then bind it to a button on your mouse.

Answer (score 0):

If the TYON mouse came with the **Swarm** software from ROCCAT then you can add the macros from there.

My suggestion is not to use the macro softwares bundled with the every mouse but go towards the **AutoHotKey** as it is a more stable and powerful tool